# How can i use triggred oracle from smite in the best way

Tags: league-of-legends

Can anyone explain to me how to know exactly when the oracle triggers from smite usage and how can i make the best use of my smite to get better value from  my oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a list of the buffs you get for smiting each jungle monster

> **Blue Sentinel**: restore a large amount of mana over 2 seconds (25% of your maximum mana).
>
> **Red Brambleback**: restore a large amount of health instantly (20% of your maximum health).
>
> **Ancient Krug**: for 90 seconds every 6th basic attack stuns minions and monsters. Additionally, you can attack a tower to expend the buff early -
>    dealing a large amount of bonus true damage (65 + 15 × level).
>
> **Crimson Raptor**: grant you true sight for a short duration the next time you are spotted by an enemy ward for 90 seconds.
>
> **Greater Murk Wolf**: summon a rift spirit that grants sight over the nearby crossroads for 90 seconds. Whenever an enemy champion comes in range of the nature spirit, it will chase them for a short duration.
>
> **Gromp**: for 90 seconds, poisons enemies who attack you, dealing 10 + (5% bonus health) magic damage over 3 seconds.

about the raptors - you get a buff that for the next 90 seconds if you step next to an enemy ward, you will recieve an oracle buff for a short duration. if you're playing low-level ranked or non-ranked games I'd suggest getting other buffs mainly and using this oracle buff to clear baron / dragon from wards

Comment: if you're playing low-level ranked or non-ranked games I'd suggest getting other buffs mainly and using this oracle buff to clear baron / dragon from `Wards` ?